# Reg: Error With IP Address while connecting the WiFi Direct Device?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I was able to connect the WiFi Direct device from Application, While connecting Device is acting as Group Owner and Non-Group Owner. I mainly face this issue in Nexus device. After connecting if device act as Group Owner, then wrong IP Address is showing. This is the code I am using.

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = mPeers.get(arg2).deviceAddress;
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
config.groupOwnerIntent=0;
mWifiP2pManager.connect(mChannel, config, new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    isconnected=true;
}
@Override
public void onFailure(int reason) {
    Toast.makeText(ConfigureNetworkActivity.this, "Connect failed."+reason,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

});

I am using this code to retrieve the IP Address.
info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
How we can we retrieve correct IP address, if Device act as Group Owner after connection?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

By using this code I am able to retrieve the IP Address of Connected WiFi Direct device. If it is Group Owner.

```
public static String getIPFromMac(String MAC) {
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
        if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
            // Basic sanity check
            String device = splitted[5];
            if (device.matches(".*p2p-p2p0.*")){
                String mac = splitted[3];
                if (mac.matches(MAC)) {
                    return splitted[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return null;
```

}

Thanks..